# MYSQL Inserting an ID based upon the database being selected?

Tags: mysql

Here's what I'm working with so far (work in progress):

```
INSERT INTO customer_bi.flight_search (
SELECT
    NULL,
    count(temp.audit_id) AS `count`,
    temp.destination,
    temp.audit_subsite_id,
    temp.subsite_desc,
    DATE_FORMAT(temp.audit_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS search_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            a.audit_id,
            fs.destination,
            a.audit_subsite_id,
            s.subsite_desc,
            a.audit_date
        FROM
            audit_flight_search fs
        INNER JOIN audit a ON a.audit_id = fs.audit_id
        INNER JOIN gns.subsite s ON a.audit_subsite_id = s.subsite_id
        WHERE
            a.audit_date >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND a.audit_date < CURRENT_DATE()
        AND fs.flight_type = 'ROUNDTRIP'
        and (a.audit_member_id IS NULL OR a.audit_member_id != 10172424)
    ) temp
GROUP BY
    temp.subsite_desc,
    temp.destination
ORDER BY
    temp.subsite_desc ASC,
    `count` DESC
)
```

In the database customer_bi, I have a table that lists all of our other databases with IDs. For example GNS has an ID of 4. What I'm looking to do is insert that ID based upon database name in the second inner join (gns.subsite in this example). I've searched and have not been able to find an answer and I don't really know PHP so I can't use that as a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a join in

```
gns.subsite s
```

But the id you are looking for is not in your selection list

```
a.audit_id,
fs.destination,
a.audit_subsite_id,
s.subsite_desc,
a.audit_date
```

Is missing

```
s.subsite_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this issue by creating a 1 cell table in each of the databases to hold the ID and added a subquery. This fixed the issue:

```
INSERT INTO customer_bi.flight_search (
SELECT
    NULL,
    count(temp.audit_id) AS `count`,
    temp.destination,
    temp.db_id,
    temp.audit_subsite_id,
    temp.subsite_desc,
    DATE_FORMAT(temp.audit_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS search_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            a.audit_id,
            fs.destination,
            (SELECT
                db_id
             FROM gns.db_id) as db_id,
            a.audit_subsite_id,
            s.subsite_desc,
            a.audit_date
        FROM
            audit_flight_search fs
        INNER JOIN audit a ON a.audit_id = fs.audit_id
        INNER JOIN gns.subsite s ON a.audit_subsite_id = s.subsite_id
        WHERE
            a.audit_date >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND a.audit_date < CURRENT_DATE()
        AND fs.flight_type = 'ROUNDTRIP'
        and (a.audit_member_id IS NULL OR a.audit_member_id != 10172424)
    ) temp
GROUP BY
    temp.subsite_desc,
    temp.destination
ORDER BY
    temp.subsite_desc ASC,
    `count` DESC
)
```